# Rate limit Shopify API calls in Ruby

Tags: ruby, shopify

I am using Shopify's `shopify_api` gem in Ruby.

I am updating each products cost and price from an external source however I am hitting the API limits and receiving `429 Too Many Requests` (https://help.shopify.com/en/api/reference/rest-admin-api-rate-limits).

How can I edit the below to respect the API limits?

I would rather use the data supplied in `X-Shopify-Shop-Api-Call-Limit` and `Retry-After` rather than adding a fixed `sleep`.

```
products = ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, :params => {:limit => limit})

products.each do |product|
                variant = ShopifyAPI::Variant.find(product.variants.first.id)

                variant.price = price
                variant.save

                inventoryitem = ShopifyAPI::InventoryItem.find(product.variants.first.inventory_item_id)

                inventoryitem.cost = cost
                inventoryitem.save
        end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

There's a gem from Shopify itself to help with rate limiting: https://github.com/Shopify/limiter.

Comment: Have you used that Gem? Does it work well? Do you have any example uses of it you can post as a gist or something? It seems interesting, but also kind of murky how that interacts with Active Resource.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest approach is to Monkeypatch ActiveResource. Here is a repo that does all the work for you.

https://github.com/mikeyhew/shopify_api_mixins

Answer (score 0):

> I would rather use the data supplied in X-Shopify-Shop-Api-Call-Limit
>   and Retry-After rather than adding a fixed sleep.

The [Shopify API Retry gem](https://github.com/ScreenStaring/shopify_api_retry) does this. It looks to `Retry-After` header but does use fixed sleep. No way around sleeping. How else to wait?

It does not do any "monkey patching". This is good. Monkey patching likely will cause problem at some point.

To use with your code

```
products = ShopifyAPIRetry.retry { ShopifyAPI::Product.find(:all, :params => {:limit => limit}) }
products.each do |product|
  variant = ShopifyAPIRetry.retry { ShopifyAPI::Variant.find(product.variants.first.id) }

  variant.price = price
  ShopifyAPIRetry.retry { variant.save }

  inventoryitem = ShopifyAPIRetry.retry { ShopifyAPI::InventoryItem.find(product.variants.first.inventory_item_id) }

  inventoryitem.cost = cost
  ShopifyAPIRetry.retry { inventoryitem.save }
end
```

Having to call `retry` everywhere is not that nice. You could possibly consolidate some places into single call.

Comment: Interesting approach... :)